# python: list of tuples search

Tags: python, list, search, tuples

Need some help here

`num = [(1,4,5,30,33,41,52),(2,10,11,29,30,36,47),(3,15,25,37,38,58,59)]`

if the last 6 digits are located to return the first digit.

example if finds 10,11,29,30,36,47 return 2

Comment: ...and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `next` similair to user's approach:

```
num = [(1,4,5,30,33,41,52),(2,10,11,29,30,36,47),(3,15,25,37,38,58,59)]
to_find = [10,11,29,30,36,47]

print(next(n for n, *nums in num if nums == to_find))
```

---

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` with a conditional generator expression:

```
num = [(1,4,5,30,33,41,52),(2,10,11,29,30,36,47),(3,15,25,37,38,58,59)]
search = 11

next(first for first, *rest in num if search in rest)
# 2
```